# Store values of a csv in different colums of table database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I need to do a form that stores values of a csv in a table database, the form I just did works but I need to store the values in a specific order.

This is the csv im working with:

[image: csv]

I need to store the values in color in different colums of a table database like this:

[image: csv]

But when I run the form the values store like this:

[image: example]

This is my form:

```
 <div class="container">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['uploadBtn'])){
    $fileName=$_FILES['myFile']['name'];
    $fileTmpName=$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];
   
    $fileExtension=pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $allowedType = array('csv');
    if(!in_array($fileExtension,$allowedType)){?>

        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            INVALID FILE
        </div>
    <?php }else{
        
        
        

        $handle = fopen($fileTmpName, 'r');
$k = 0;
$energies = [];
while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',')) !== FALSE) {
  $k++;
  if ( $k > 1 ) {
        $energies[] = $myData[3];
     }
}


list($e1, $e2, $e3) = $energies;
$query = "INSERT INTO metlab.table (energy1, energy2, energy3) VALUES ($e1, $e2, $e3)";

$run = mysql_query($query);
        
        
        
        
        if(!$run){
            die("error in uploading file".mysql_error());
        }else{ ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    SUCCESS
                </div>
    <?php   }
    }
}
    ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3 class="text-center">
        RESULTS
    </h3></hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="file" name="myFile" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name ="uploadBtn" class="btn btn-info">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It appears that `energy1` is working fine, so that's a start. You just need to add the others in.

Comment: **1.** Don't use the deprecated and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead. **2.** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries, which can be used if you use the above mentioned MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ..............

    $handle = fopen($fileTmpName, 'r');
    $k = 0;
    $energies = [];
    while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',')) !== FALSE) {
      $k++;
      if ( $k > 1 ) {
            $energies[] = $myData[3];
         }
    }

    // 1 method
    // $values = join(',', $energies);
    // $query = "INSERT INTO metlab.table (energy1, energy2, energy3) VALUES ($values)";

    // 2 method
    list($e1, $e2, $e3) = $energies;
    $query = "INSERT INTO metlab.table (energy1, energy2, energy3) VALUES ($e1, $e2, $e3)";

    $run = mysql_query($query);

    ..............
```

Comment: So just try to change these lines: list($e1, $e2, $e3) = $energies;  $query = "INSERT INTO metlab.table (energy1, energy2, energy3) VALUES ($e1, $e2, $e3)";

Comment: I changed the code (added alternative way) right now. Should works )

Comment: im checking dude :)

Comment: dude, can you check the actual code I updated it, I cant get it to work I dont know what im doing wrong u.u

Comment: dude it works I just changed this:  $energies = [];
to this
 $energies = array ();
Im gonna do more tests but it looks like working

Comment: here you go :) that was just php-version conflict, sorry for confusion... )

Answer (score 1):

When you parse a CSV file, you parse it row by row. So what is currently happening is expected behaviour from your code sample.

The problem you have is you're wanting to get all 3 `energy` values at once to be persisted into one row within your table.

You would need to parse your CSV file first and then persist the data. Like so;

```
$handle = fopen($fileTmpName, 'r');
$k = 0;
$energies = [];
while (($myData = fgetcsv($handle,1000,',')) !== FALSE) {
  $k++;
  if ( $k > 1 ) {
        // hold onto your values for later.
        $energies[] = $myData[3];
     }
}

// ... you can now persist them in a horizontal table.
```

My only question is: Is there only going to be 3 "energies"? What about 4, 5, 6 etc? This would impact your table design. Maybe a design for your table would be:

id |
energy_type
 | energy_value

This way you can account for new `energy_types` in an easier to maintain way.

Note: Please use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: the csv always shows energy1 2 and 3(yellow,green,orange) no more

Comment: Okay. The code snippet I've provided will help you achieve what you wanted. The table design is only a consideration based on the scope of your application.

Comment: and after that how can I do the insert Im not that pro sorry :/